# Bootstrap div Auto resize when other grid is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have two Bootstrap div like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
     Grid 1
    </div>
    <div  class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
      Grid 2    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When i **Hide(visibility:hidden)** one of the div i need the result like

[image]

Is this possible with Bootstrap grid system, or using jquery and all. Please help how this can achievable.

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4?

Comment: Yes i am using BS4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Flex`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">
     Grid 1
    </div>
    <div  class="col" style="background-color:pink;">
      Grid 2    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col" style="background-color:yellow;">
     Grid 1
    </div>
    <div  class="col" style="background-color:pink; display:none">
    Grid 2    
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

also `visibility:hidden` to `display:none`

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/bx8j06h1/5/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite same answer as question wants, but came here looking for how to resize element based on state of another element.  For anyone using angular, see `ng-class` directive

```
<div ng-class="vm.someFlag? 'col-sm-12' : 'col-sm-8'">
```